# Redirect the user to the top of the screen (smartphones)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-safari

I would like to know if there is any jQuery/Javascript events that allow to redirect users to the top of a smartphone screen. This is to always display the top safari bar.

Comment: Stick and anchor tag. Simple, no JS needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't really understand how adding an anchor will display the top safari bar? I add Shadowpat's solution, I'm redirected to the top of the page but not to the top of the screen. (the top safari bar isn't display)

Comment: Now I get what you want. And sorry, I don't have a clue. Looks like an app thing, not something you would achieve from a web page. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your honesty, enjoy your day

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is use an anchor.
Put this at the top of the page:

```
<a name="top"></a>
```

Add this where you want the link to the top of the page to be:

```
<a href="#top">Go to Top</a>
```

Here is the link for more info: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did what you said. When I'm cliking on the link I'm redirecting to the top of the html document where I put my link. Otherwise, I would like to display the top safari bar. Any ideas? thanks again =)

Comment: You mean, the link is clicked and if you are not at the top of the page you will be brought to the top, but if you are already at the top then the address bar is shown? Let me know if this is what you mean

Comment: Ok, i found out what you mean now! This website may be of help to you:  http://goo.gl/GjXHV Let me know if you need further guidance or if the website doesn't help.